# Getting page not found error when updating profile

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use a form to edit the details of a profile. However, I keep encountering this error message

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  POST

this is edit html file

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="app-instructor-profile.html" method="post" >
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="photo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Avatar</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="media v-middle">
                            <div class="media-left">
                              <div class="icon-block width-100 bg-grey-100">
                                <i class="fa fa-photo text-light"></i>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                              <a href="#" class="btn btn-white btn-sm paper-shadow relative" data-z="0.5" data-hover-z="1" data-animated> Add Image<i class="fa fa-upl"></i></a>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-control-material">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder= {{ user.first_name }}>
                                <label for="first_name"></label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-control-material">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" placeholder={{ user.last_name }}>
                                <label for="last_name"></label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-control-material">
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder={{ user.email }}>
                              <label for="inputEmail3"></label>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Change Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-control-material">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                            <label for="inputPassword3">Password</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-6">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                            <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" checked="">
                            <label for="checkbox3">Subscribe to our Newsletter</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group margin-none">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary paper-shadow relative" data-z="0.5" data-hover-z="1" data-animated>Save Changes</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
...
class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Profile of user {}".format(self.user.username)

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_or_update(sender, instance,created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Mentor.objects.create(user=instance)
```

forms.py

```
class MentorSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = forms.URLField(max_length=200)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.is_teacher = True
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        mentor = Mentor.objects.create(
            user=user,
            linkedin=self.cleaned_data['linkedin']
        )
        return user
#edit mentor profile
class MentorProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mentor
        exclude = ['user']
```

and views.py (teachers.py)

```
...
#edit mentor profile
def edit_user(request):
    user = request.user
    form = MentorProfileForm(initial={'first_name':user.first_name,'last_name':user.last_name,'email':user.email})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
            user.email = request.POST['email']
            user.password = request.POST['password']
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s'%(reverse('profile')))
    context = {
        "form":form
    }
    return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/app-instructor-profile.html', context)
```

Comment: You have template name in form action `action="app-instructor-profile.html"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are submitting the form to some template name `app-instructor-profile.html` (probably by mistake). You should replace it with current request's full path  `action="{{ request.get_full_path }}"` or use url tag for named routes. like this

```
action="{% url 'your_url_name' %}"
```

Comment: The view seems to take GET and POST, this would suggest that the `action` attribute is not needed at all as the form should just be posting to the same URL. Although the `request.POST` data should probably be passed to the form instead of manually extracting the data

Comment: @IainShelvington Yeah, that would be good too. But I find `request.full_path` more explicit than omitting it. Just an opinion :)

Comment: Fair enough, the only issue with using a `url` tag like this is that you lose any query (GET) parameters. Although `request.get_full_path` should resolve that

Comment: True, but OP was not making use of query-string so I added named URL as an option.